# How to filter xray traces by segment or subsegment

Tags: aws-xray

I am new to using xray and have instrumented my lambdas with a number of segments/subsegments to start tracing. This is helpful in analyzing a single trace, but I need better filtering of traces. I've read about [how to use filter expressions in the console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-console-filters.html) but am not sure how to use it beyond the simple examples the article provides. I'd like to filter traces by existence of a segment or subsegment, or perhaps by the duration of a subsegment.

For example, I want to find traces that have the Initialization phase (e.g. lambda cold start occurred) or where Initialization had a duration > 100ms. I also have named subsegments which would be useful in a similar way, for instance show me traces where the "select_from_ctac_lg" subsegment had a duration > 500ms.

Is this possible?

Then if I'm able to do filtering, I'd ideally also like to graph some results. The console has a "Response Time Distribution of Traces", so a similar graph of duration of the "select_from_ctac_lg" subsegment would be very useful.